# How do I solve this puzzle in The Challenge?

Tags: the-witness

I've been trying for so long but couldn't do this. I was trying to find different ways by drawing the lines on this picture on my computer but all won't work (I play on PS4 btw.) This is in the challenge. It's a symmetry puzzle with the hexagon dots.  [image]

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

New and updated with colour

> [image: Solution]

Old solution without colour

> [image: Old Solution]
>  [link](https://windmill.thefifthmatt.com/build/CA0SAggDEgIIBhICCAYSAigHEgIIBhICCAYSAggEEgIoAhICCAYSAigHEgIIBhICKAQSAggGEgIIBhICCAYSAggGEgIIBhICCAYSAggGEgASAggGEgIIBhICCAYSAigIEgIIBhICKAMSAggGEgIIBhICCAYSAggGEgASAggGEgIIBhICCAYSAggGEgIIBhICKAISAggFEgIIBhICCAYSABICCAYSABICCAYSAigHEgIIBhICCAYSAggFEgIIBhICCAYSAggGEgIoAxICCAYSAggGEgIIBhIAEgIIBhICCAYSAigHEgIIBhIAEgIIBhIAEgIIBhICCAYSAigDEgIIBhICCAYSAggGEgIIBhICCAYSABICCAYSAggGEgIIBhICCAYSAigDEgIIBhICKAUSAggFEgIoAhICCAYSAggGEgIIBhIAEgIIBhICCAYSAggGEgIIBhICCAYSAggGEgIIBhICKAQSAggGEgIoBxICCAYSABICCAUSAggEEgIIBhICCAYSAigEEgIIBRICKAISAggGEgIIBhICCAMYBA==_0) to the puzzle solution thing (not sure what to call it).